# TeXMaker not starting on linux

Tags: texmaker

TeXMaker randomly stopped working for no apparent reason.  When I type the command, it just returns to the command prompt with no program launching and no output or errors at all.  If I launch it a different way, the same thing happens, absolutely nothing.  This happened literally after closing the program and then attempting to reopen it.  I tried reinstalling texmaker from synaptic, which did nothing, and then completely uninstalling it, installing all recommended upgrades, and then reinstalling it, which did nothing.  LaTeX itself works fine and is still installed, although for some reason the expex package randomly got uninstalled and had to be installed again, but after doing that it works fine from both the command line and in other TeX editors, while TeXMaker is still nonfunctional.  What do I have to do to get TeXMaker to work again?  I found another editor to use on synaptic for the time being, but I don't like it and would like to have TeXMaker working again.

Comment: Since the underlying TeX distribution appears to be working, it may be more productive to take up your TeXmaker-related issue with the TeXmaker distributor than to post it to TeX.SE.

Comment: Does it start, if you try another user? Have you tried, removing `~/.config/Texmakerrc` and `~/.config/xm1/texmaker.ini` and `~/.config/xm1/texmakerapp.ini` and `~/.config/xm1/texmakerpdfview.ini`? Which alternative editor have you tested? Maybe TeXstudio would be an alternative.

Comment: It works for me and if I reinstall it it works again without problems, so it is not easy to answer your question with that data. Check if it works for a completely new user. If so, the problem could be a corrupt configuration or temporal file somewhere in your `/home/faiuwle` but not really a problem of the installation.

Comment: Thank you, @cabohah, that did it!